# ASP.Net Core MVC Prefix before all Routes needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, traefik

As in the Title I have an ASP.NET Core MVC Application. (.NET Core 3.0) 
I also have a Traefik reverse-proxy (Traefik version 1.7.10)

I want to access my ASP.NET like "www.randomname.com/service1/Home"

Is there a way to set the "service1" prefix before every route?

The Problem is that some Css and js files dont get the prefix. 
 http://randomname.com/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
Gives an error 
 http://randomname.com/service1/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
Works

This Problem is also only on the Linux server after i deployed it.
In VisualStudio it isnt a problem

Comment: You don't have to do it. you can configure is IIS and set root folder url www.randomname.com/service1

Comment: @RajeshG where can I configure this?

Comment: Create a sub directory called service1 under your website in IIS. Right click on the sub directory and select Convert to application. You need to host the application inside this sub directory.

Comment: @RajeshG Im relatively new to this. With IIS you mean the wwwroot folder?
I edited the post to make it clearer

Comment: If your website is hosted in windows server using IIS then only my suggestion work. If you are self hosting your application then above suggestions won't work.